# trindade and the use of the word "estão"

Tags: português-brasileiro

This question is going to be a bit of religious nature,
but it does contain something gramatical.

Suppose that you believe in the *trindade* (or 
the *Holy Trinity* in English), and that
the end of the world, as prophecied in the *Revelation*,
is just coming right now.

So you would be see zillions of angels flying in the sky 
going up and down all over the world, and o próprio Deus, 
o próprio Jesus, and o espírito santo would come back to 
this world once again in some ways (I can't be specific 
on how they are coming because the notion of trindade
 is just too mysterious to be describable with my poor 
knowledges).

Now, the question is, would you say

o próprio Deus, o próprio Jesus, e o espirito santo
*estão* aqui ?

I am asking this question because I heard a guy 
who I guess is a Catholic or Protestant might have
sung a song where he says *estão* in this kind of situation.

But *estão* is the third person plural form of *estar*, and
this sounds inconsistent with trindade.

By the way, the song I heard is *Anjos de Deus* 
sung by Elizeu Gomes.

Any effort for clarifying on this matter
would be really appreciated.

Comment: Aqui, as perguntas sāo normalmente em Português.

Comment: When you refer to, and even enumerate the persons of the trinity, you're referring to the (more than one) parts, so -- from the *purely grammatical* standpoint -- you clearly should use the plural.

Comment: @PedroLobito Na verdade tanto perguntas em português quanto em inglês são aceitas.

Comment: @stafusa Okay. Your answer removed my worry; I love essa cancão by Gomes, and from now on, I can listen to Gomes without any suspicion!

Comment: @PedroLobito I am a novice. That would be impossible.

Comment: It is as @stafusa says: **questions in English are perfectly acceptable here**.

Comment: "A Santíssima Trindade"  is a unity and, therefore, singular.    O Pai, o Filho e o Espírito Santo are parts and, therefore, plural.

Comment: @Centaurus Oh right, is that what was meant? Gees.

Comment: @Lambie  I guess my comment didn't convey what I meant it to.   A necklace is one piece of jewelry and therefore singular.  The pearls are parts and when you refer to more than one, they're plural.

Comment: @Centaurus Não o seu comentário. A pergunta foi mal feita.

Answer (score 1):

Isto depende de quem você está falando, exemplos:

- A santíssima trindade **está** presente
- Jesus, Maria e José **estão** presentes
- Nós **estamos** aqui
- Eles **estão** em algum lugar

Uma maneira fácil é analisar qual o pronome poderia ser usado para substituição e concordar com o pronome.

---

This depends on who or what you are talking about; examples:

- A santíssima trindade **está** presente (she/it is present)
- Jesus, Maria e José **estão** presentes (they are present)
- Nós **estamos** aqui (we are here)
- Eles **estão** em algum lugar (they are somewhere)

A simple way is to analyze which pronoun ([eu,] tu, ele/ela, nós, vós, eles/elas) could be used as a replacement for the noun, and then ensure that the verb agrees with the pronoun - third person singular, or first plural, or third plural, or...

Comment: muito obrigado por seu suporte! mas junto em inglês, por favor. tenho que procuro tanto com dicionário.